# GWT grid with 200 columns and 500 lines

Tags: java, gwt

I would to create a speed GWT grid who contains 200 columns and 500 lines.
I tested ''DataGrid'' from GWT, ''Grid'' from GXT2 and GXT3, ''Grid'' with ''LiveGridView'' from GXT3.

With live grid, it's a little faster, but it's very good.
Do you know a fast grid? 
Or do you know a solution for not load any columns in memory, like live grid for columns?

Thanks.
Mathieu

Comment: i dont know if you need to interact a lot with the grid, but to display a big grid the best performance you will get if you build the whole grid as html and inject it directly in the DOM

Comment: Thanks, Normally, I just have to make the cell selection